# How to checkout submodule in Makefile in subdirectory

Tags: git, makefile

Right now that is what I have :

```
data:

    git checkout master -C $(DATA_DIR)
    git pull -C $(DATA_DIR)
```

Submodule is located in DATA_DIR.

The problem with what I have is when I do "make data", I get the following error : "error : unkown switch 'C'". I assume it is because git assumes -C is a command for itself rather than a command for the Makefile, because after it lists me all the commands I can use in git.

My question is this : How can I checkout the submodule located in DATA_DIR.

Comment: Rather than remembering to put `-C` on every git command, it might be simpler to set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable and use git normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead

```
git -C $(DATA_DIR) pull
```

`-C` applies to the [`git` command itself](https://git-scm.com/docs/git), not as an option of pull.

```
-C <path>
```

> Run as if git was started in `<path>` instead of the current working directory.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you for taking your time to answer my question!